# Why is [[ ! -f $(find "${mydir}" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -mtime -1) ]] unexpectedly true?

Tags: bash, if-statement

Can someone advise of a better way to perform this check?

This statement evaluates to true even if there are no csv files in mydir, can someone assist?  I am checking if there are files that (1) Are one day or less older (2) Have .csv extension (3) Are not in sub-directories

```
if [[ ! -f $(find "${mydir}" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -mtime -1) ]]; then
```

In debug, it evaluates this `[[ ! -f '' ]]` to true; how to fix that? This did not work either

```
[[ ! -f $(find "${mydir}" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -mtime -1) ]] && [[ -f "" ]]
```

Comment: This isn't reliable even in the case where there *are* multiple files. If `find` returns two names, `-f` will be false when given a string with multiple names in it (because combining those two names together doesn't result in the name of a single file that *does* exist).

Comment: Anyhow, *of course* `[[ ! -f "" ]]` will be true, because `''` is no file, and the `!` negates it.

Comment: ...anyhow, I don't currently see how the behavior is surprising here.

Comment: To reiterate again, in response to edits: Why do you think `[[ ! -f '' ]]` being true is **wrong**? The `!` is a negation; it changes true things to be false, and false things to be true.

Comment: (BTW, the long-winded test harness in my answer is intended to serve as an example of how to write code in questions that complies with [mcve] guidelines -- doing all the setup needed to be copy-and-paste-to-test).

Answer (score 2):

Let's try an experiment here, using your original code wrapped in a function:

```
at_least_one_recent_csv() {
  [[ -f $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -mtime -1 -print) ]]
}

in_tempdir() {                     # run the command we're passed in a temporary directory
  local tempdir retval
  tempdir=$(mktemp -d "/tmp/test.XXXXXX")
  (cd "$tempdir" && "$@"); retval=$?
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
  return "$retval"
}

with_garbage() {                               # create content find is supposed to ignore
  mkdir -p dir; touch dir/ignored.csv          # subdirectories are ignored
  touch -d "3 days ago" old.csv                # files more than a day old are ignored
  touch not-a-csv.txt;                         # non-*.csv files are ignored
  "$@"
}

with_no_csvs() { "$@"; }                         # our test cases! This one's a noop
with_one_csv() { touch one.csv; "$@"; }          # ...whereas here we create one new CSV 
with_two_csvs() { touch one.csv two.csv; "$@"; } # ...and here we create two.

print_exit_status() {                # run a command, print what it was and its exit status
  local cmd_str retval
  printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$@"       # generate a string that represents the command
  "$@"; retval=$?                    # actually *run* the command and capture its status
  echo "The exit status of ${cmd_str% } is $retval" >&2  # print command & status
  return "$retval"                   # and then return that exit status to our caller
}

print_exit_status in_tempdir with_garbage with_no_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv
print_exit_status in_tempdir with_garbage with_one_csv at_least_one_recent_csv
print_exit_status in_tempdir with_garbage with_two_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv
```

...emits as output:

```
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_no_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv is 1
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_one_csv at_least_one_recent_csv is 0
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_two_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv is 1
```

...because when `find` has two results, concatenating them together doesn't yield a single filename which `test -f` can identify as existing. Thus, we're correctly returning `false` in the zero-results case, and correctly returning `true` in the one-result case, but incorrectly returning `false` in the two-or-more case.

---

**However**, if we added `-quit` (so `find` stops printing after one result) and removed the `!`, and thus defined `at_least_one_recent_csv` like so:

```
at_least_one_recent_csv() {
  [[ $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -mtime -1 -print -quit) ]]
}
```

...output would be, correctly:

```
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_no_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv is 1
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_one_csv at_least_one_recent_csv is 0
The exit status of in_tempdir with_garbage with_two_csvs at_least_one_recent_csv is 0
```

...such that `at_least_one_recent_csv` is returning a 0 (truthy) value only if... there's actually one or more recently-created CSV. :)